# Why am I getting ClassCastException when sub-classing GridView?

Tags: android

It's strange; for some reason, I'm having a hard time getting a sub-class of GridView to cast properly. I get `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridView cannot be cast to com.dobydigital.dobixchange.CustomGridView` when trying to cast my CustomGridView. Here is my code

CustomGridView.java

```
import android.widget.GridView;
public class CustomGridView extends GridView {
```

FileBrowserFragment.java

```
//# Other stuff omitted for brevity
private CustomGridView gridView;
public class FileBrowserFragment extends Fragment {
//# Stuff
}
//# .........
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //# This cast here throws the exception
    gridView = (CustomGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
```

file_browser.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_node"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.dobydigital.dobixchange.CustomGridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:layout_weight="80" >
    <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/image_tile -->
</com.dobydigital.dobixchange.CustomGridView>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Select this Directory" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't figure out what's going on. I've never had problems subclassing layouts before.

Comment: What does `getView()` do? Also, are you importing the right 'R' file?

Comment: You don't need to cast your custom GridView into a regular GridView, there really is no need. What are you trying to do with the custom GridView?

Comment: I have to use getView() inside a Fragment to get a reference to an Inflated view (In this case, it's the root node, a LinearLayout). There is no simple "findViewById()" for a Fragment class.

Comment: @Alex, Yes, I do indeed need to subclass the GridView. There are several methods that I need to override.

Comment: I did not say you couldn't subclass... What I am saying is that you don't need to CAST it as a CustomGridView. There's really no need to cast to a subclass if you are a superclass if you are just overriding methods.

Comment: I understand about not having to cast it. It's the fact that it's *not* casting that has me concerned, as it's a valid cast. Also, it's concerning that the constructor for the CustomGridView (none of the overloaded constructors, either) are firing.

Comment: Also, just to add, none of the overridden methods are firing off. It's weird, I can't track down the problem. like I said in the original post, I've never had any problems overriding a layout before. I can only assume it has something to do with being inside a Fragment, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Just a shoot in the dark: Are you sure you inflate&return your _file_browser.xml_ in `onCreateView()`? You may accidentally inflate another layout also containing a `GridView` with the same id

Comment: Actually mate, that was the problem. I actually found out about 20 minutes ago that this was the problem. I actually did a bit of a rewrite earlier, and forgot to get rid of the old XML file. If you post this reply as an answer, I'll mark yours as the solution :)

Comment: @XaeroDegreaz These things happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments of the question: You accidentally inflate & return a wrong layout in `onCreateView()` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
gridView = (CustomGridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
```

get rid of the getView()

Comment: I can't, this is inside a Fragment.